# opening and closing an array of pop open pages

Tags: javascript

Hi I have some code that on load this is called

```
function arrayDeclare(){
    var subPages = new Array();
    return subPages;}
```

Then with a button click this function is called

```
function addAndOpenPage(URL, subPages){
    subPages.push("URL");
    var newWindow=window.open("URL");

}
```

Then on another button click this function is called

```
function closeTabs(subPages){
for(var i=0; i<subPages.length; i++){
window.close(subPages[i]);}
```

}

The code is supposed to declare an Array with onload. Then open a new tab with the next button click. Then when another button is clicked it is supposed to close all the opened tabs. Can anyone tell me how to get this working.

Answer (score 0):

As they say - "You're not using it right" :)

Look here - http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_close.asp

The idea is that window.close() doesn't accept a URL parameter as window.open() does - but you need to save the window object itself to close it, such as (from W3Schools):

```
myWindow = window.open("","myWindow","width=200,height=100");
myWindow.document.write("<p>This is 'myWindow'</p>");
myWindow.close();
```

So, for your code - you need to save the window objects:

```
function addAndOpenPage(URL, subPages){
var newWindow=window.open("URL");
subPages.push(newWindow);
}

function closeTabs(subPages){
for(var i=0; i<subPages.length; i++){
subPages[i].close();
}
}
```

I didn't test this code - but I believe it should work.

Comment: I could be doing something wrong but I can't get it to open a new window. Every thing appears ok but it just won't work. I moved the array and newWindow declaration to a section of javascript on the main page and still nothing. On the function call I put the URL in single quotes. but still no result.